# Missing dots in ToC for chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, memoir

I am using the starred version of `\chapter` and `\section` to avoid the numbering of chapter and section. To have the title of chapters in ToC I use `\addcontentsline{toc}{<xxx>}`.

This results in no dots between title of chapter and page number in the ToC.

How do I get the dots back in the line?

Comment: You should use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}` instead of `\chapter*` and `\section*` all over. In this way you'll need no explicit `\addcontentsline`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default layout of the ToC for chapters (starred or not) under [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) is to have no dots. This is set internally by

```
\newcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftnodots}
```

If you want dots, it's best to set it to match that of the sectional unit dots, which is the same as `\cftdotsep`. As such, using

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}% Chapters should use dots in ToC
```

works.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}% Chapters should use dots in ToC
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\chapter*{A starred chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}A starred chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: However, in your screenshot there aren't dots for the last level of headings for an entry. How to fix that?

Comment: @Zelphir: What do you mean by "last level"?

Comment: For example there is the following: `1 A chapter` instead of `1. A chapter` For me this _sounds_ wrong. I don't know how it is in English, but at least in German you'd rather say "First ... A chapter", so you'd use an ordinal number, instead of just a number. That's why I'd like to have a dot there. Also I think it's more logical: _"The first chapter is A chapter"_ (in that order, reading from left to right) instead of _"One chapter is A chapter."_ not including any indication that the number stands for a rank within the chapter hierarchy.